# Dynamic interfaces with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am simplifying the question here .

```
interface Identity{
    name: string;
}
```

Another generic interface

```
interface State<T extends Identity>{
    [T.name] : StateContainer<T>
}
```

But this wont work as it gives error

> Cannot find T

If I try to generate it by keeping it inside a function

```
function generate(c : Identity){
    interface State<T>{
        [c.name]: StateContainer<T>
    }
}
```

It says

> A computed property name in an interface must directly refer to built-in symbol.

My desired output is to have dynamic interface such that . `State<Tenant>` should behave

```
interface State{
    'tenant': ....
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm kinda on a Typescript side here because I don't understand your code as well

Comment: Am actually trying to generalize code using generics , i updated my expected output

Comment: What is the connection between `Tenant` type and `'tenant'` string? Where the latter is supposed to be retrieved from?

Comment: It can extend from `Identity` and have a `name` attribute inside `Tenant` or ... every function has name property so I can directly call `Tenant.name`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type State<T extends Identity> = {
    [P in keyof T] : StateContainer<T>
}
```

Comment: It gives error : `A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
Cannot find name 'keyof'.` Did you try it and worked for you .

Comment: Here's an [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Identity%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20StateContainer%3CT%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20object%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Tenant%20extends%20Identity%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20sometenantprop%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%3CT%20extends%20Identity%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%20%3A%20StateContainer%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20x%3A%20State%3CTenant%3E%3B%0D%0Ax.sometenantprop)

Comment: But judging by your updated example, looks like you want the property name from the runtime value for `Identity.name`. I do not think that will work as interfaces are available at compile-time only.